# Microsoft.Office.Word.Server SharePoint 2013 Foundation

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, word-automation

I was wondering if someone could please confirm that my understanding of the following is correct:

The assembly '***Microsoft.office.word.server***' is part of the '***Word Automation Services***' service, which is not available as part of SharePoint 2013 Foundation.

Currently I am supporting a SharePoint 2013 Foundation environment on Windows Server 2012 where this error is being received when trying to use a 3rd party add-on (not installed by myself). The add-on developer have told us to install the assembly, however I don't believe this is possible.

Is it possible to confirm if my understanding of this is correct, that would be great.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct. Word Automation Services is a SharePoint Server feature included in Standard and Enterprise.

The vendor is asking you to violate the license.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my understanding Trevor.